# javascript ctypes String to unsigned char

Tags: javascript, c, firefox, firefox-addon, jsctypes

I have a shared C library that is expecting `unsigned char *` as one of the paramaters

What is the best way to get a Javascript string to be an unsigned char *?

In my js file, I have the paramater declared as ctypes.unsigned_char.ptr but it won't owrk to just pass the javascript string in as that parameters

This is all being done in the context of a firefox extension. Here is my declaration of the function

```
var myfunction = mylib.declare("function",
                           ctypes.default_abi,
                           ctypes.int,
                           ctypes.unsigned_char.ptr,
                           ctypes.long);
```

Where mylib is the var i loaded the shared lib with the ctypes module.

Comment: How are you getting the javascript data to the c program?

Comment: This is a firefox extension, so I am using the ctype module and loading the shared lib. ..will post an edit with the declaration

Comment: When you say "it won't owrk to just pass the javascript string in as that parameters", what do you mean? While JavaScript internally uses UCS-2 *or* UTF-16, in practice most use UTF-16. I've had no problems passing JavaScript's strings to c libraries which want plain ASCII by declaring them as `ctypes.char.ptr`. Is there some specific character that you're trying to pass that isn't working? Are you trying to pass binary data stored in typed arrays? Are you getting some specific error message?!?

Comment: Have you read this? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Working_with_data) It explains how to convert JavaScript strings to UTF-8 and UTF-16. `unsigned_char` is pretty uncommon for a string? Are you really trying to use UTF-8, or trying to pass binary data?

Comment: I am trying to pass binary data

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I think you should close this question and re-ask it specifically with respect to passing binary (I'm assuming an array of unsigned 8bint integers) data. How did you build it? Client-side with typed-array? or server side in an image + data url ? or canvas + data url? or other?

Answer (score 1):

The following [should work](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/ctypes/tests/unit/test_jsctypes.js.in#1756):

- Declare the argument as `ctypes.uint8_t`.
- Pass the argument as `ctypes.uint8_t.ptr(new Uint8Array(...))`.